Custom Feature Map Error for VQR in Qiskit 'Input data has incorrect shape, last dimension is not equal to the number of inputs'
I am trying to use a VQR for solving a regression problem. My data has 5 features, I want to use 4 features to estimate 5th one. I made it work with ZFeatureMap but now I want to create my own feature maps to make experiments.
https://imgur.com/a/4CgYuKy
Above is the feature map I want to use
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display, Markdown
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import clear_output
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import root_mean_squared_error
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.circuit.library import RealAmplitudes, ZZFeatureMap, ZFeatureMap
from qiskit_algorithms.optimizers import COBYLA, L_BFGS_B
from qiskit_algorithms.utils import algorithm_globals
from qiskit_machine_learning.algorithms.regressors import VQR
from qiskit.circuit.library import TwoLocal


algorithm_globals.random_seed = 42

#
Data import ...
#

# Initialize the quantum circuit
rx_feature_map = QuantumCircuit(numFeature-1)
rot_angle = np.pi * 1

for _ in range(2):  # Match the same number of repetitions
    # Apply H gates
    for i in range(numFeature-1):
        rx_feature_map.h(i)
    
    # Apply Rx gates
    for i in range(numFeature-1):
        rx_feature_map.rx(rot_angle, i)
    
ansatz=RealAmplitudes(numFeature-1,entanglement='linear', reps=2)

def callback_graph_rx(weights, obj_func_eval):
    clear_output(wait=True)
    objective_func_vals.append(obj_func_eval)
    plt.title("Objective function value against iteration")
    plt.xlabel("Iteration")
    plt.ylabel("Objective function value")
    plt.plot(range(len(objective_func_vals)), objective_func_vals)
    plt.show()

vqr = VQR(
    feature_map=rx_feature_map,
    ansatz=ansatz,
    optimizer=L_BFGS_B(maxiter=2),
    callback=callback_graph_rx,
)

objective_func_vals = []
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (12, 6)

# fit regressor
vqr.fit(X_train, Y_train)

# return to default figsize
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (6, 4)

# score result
vqr.score(X_test, Y_test)


When I try to run this code I get below error.
QiskitMachineLearningError                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[95], line 5
      2 plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (12, 6)
      4 # fit regressor
----> 5 vqr.fit(X_train, Y_train)
      7 # return to default figsize
      8 plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (6, 4)

QiskitMachineLearningError: 'Input data has incorrect shape, last dimension is not equal to the number of inputs: 0, but got: 4.'


Also when I wanted to use
https://imgur.com/a/G4B2gwQ
rx_feature_map = TwoLocal(num_qubits, 'h', 'rx', reps=2, entanglement='linear')

I got below error.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CircuitError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[98], line 1
----> 1 vqr2 = VQR(
      2     feature_map=rx_feature_map,
      3     ansatz=ansatz,
      4     optimizer=L_BFGS_B(maxiter=2),
      5     callback=callback_graph_rx,
      6 )

CircuitError: "name conflict adding parameter 'θ[0]'"

